# Binary.Get: How can I be more DRY parsing complex structures?

Tags: parsing, haskell, dry

I'm parsing a complex format and it's getting really repetitious. Hoping someone has a better idea that's about 3x more DRY. Wondering if there's some magic to select the right primitive parser based on the datatype of the field.

```
data Body = Body { raw :: ByteString }
        | Far { cpuType :: !Word8
                , stdfVer :: !Word8 }
        | Prr { headNum :: !Word8
                , siteNum :: !Word8
                , partFlg :: !Word8
                , numTest :: !Word16
                , hardBin :: !Word16
                , softBin :: !Word16
                , xCoord :: !Word16
                , yCoord :: !Word16
                , testTime :: !Word32
                , partID :: ByteString
                , partTxt :: ByteString
                , partFix :: ByteString }
        deriving (Show)

getPrr :: Get Body
getPrr = do
    headNum <- u1
    siteNum <- u1
    partFlg <- u1
    numTest <- u2
    hardBin <- u2
    softBin <- u2
    xCoord <- u2
    yCoord <- u2
    testTime <- u4
    partID <- getVarLen
    partTxt <- getVarLen
    partFix <- getVarLen
    return Prr {headNum = headNum
            ,siteNum = siteNum
            ,partFlg = partFlg
            ,numTest = numTest
            ,hardBin = hardBin
            ,softBin = softBin
            ,xCoord = xCoord
            ,yCoord = yCoord
            ,testTime = testTime
            ,partID = partID
            ,partTxt = partTxt
            ,partFix = partFix }
```

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-derive

Comment: Thanks @leftaroundabout but it looks like the binary deriving is good for something like pickle but working with a specification where you have to control things like endianness and the way strings are encoded it won't be compatible. Maybe the code for how they do it could give some idea of how to make something more customized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Applicative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Applicative)!

```
getPrr :: Get Body
getPrr = Prr <$> u1 <*> u1 <*> u1 <*> u2 <*> u2 <*> u2 <*> u2 <*> u2 <*> u4 <*> getVarLen <*> getVarLen <*> getVarLen
```

Let's see how this works:

So we start with:

```
Prr :: Word8 -> Word8 -> Word8 -> Word16 -> Word16 -> Word16 -> Word16 -> Word16 -> Word32 -> ByteString -> ByteString -> ByteString -> Body
u1 :: Get Word8
u2 :: Get Word16
u4 :: Get Word32
getVarLen :: Get ByteString
```

And our operators:

```
(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b -- aka `fmap`
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

So combining those parts one by one we get

```
Prr <$> u1
    :: Get (Word8 -> Word8 -> Word16 -> Word16 -> Word16 -> Word16 -> Word16 -> Word32 -> ByteString -> ByteString -> ByteString -> Body)
Prr <$> u1 <*> u1
    :: Get (Word8 -> Word16 -> Word16 -> Word16 -> Word16 -> Word16 -> Word32 -> ByteString -> ByteString -> ByteString -> Body)
Prr <$> u1 <*> u1 <*> u1
    :: Get (Word16 -> Word16 -> Word16 -> Word16 -> Word16 -> Word32 -> ByteString -> ByteString -> ByteString -> Body)
Prr <$> u1 <*> u1 <*> u1 <*> u2
    :: Get (Word16 -> Word16 -> Word16 -> Word16 -> Word32 -> ByteString -> ByteString -> ByteString -> Body)
Prr <$> u1 <*> u1 <*> u1 <*> u2 <*> u2
    :: Get (Word16 -> Word16 -> Word16 -> Word32 -> ByteString -> ByteString -> ByteString -> Body)
Prr <$> u1 <*> u1 <*> u1 <*> u2 <*> u2 <*> u2
    :: Get (Word16 -> Word16 -> Word32 -> ByteString -> ByteString -> ByteString -> Body)
Prr <$> u1 <*> u1 <*> u1 <*> u2 <*> u2 <*> u2 <*> u2
    :: Get (Word16 -> Word32 -> ByteString -> ByteString -> ByteString -> Body)
Prr <$> u1 <*> u1 <*> u1 <*> u2 <*> u2 <*> u2 <*> u2 <*> u2
    :: Get (Word32 -> ByteString -> ByteString -> ByteString -> Body)
Prr <$> u1 <*> u1 <*> u1 <*> u2 <*> u2 <*> u2 <*> u2 <*> u2 <*> u2
    :: Get (ByteString -> ByteString -> ByteString -> Body)
Prr <$> u1 <*> u1 <*> u1 <*> u2 <*> u2 <*> u2 <*> u2 <*> u2 <*> u2 <*> getVarLen
    :: Get (ByteString -> ByteString -> Body)
Prr <$> u1 <*> u1 <*> u1 <*> u2 <*> u2 <*> u2 <*> u2 <*> u2 <*> u2 <*> getVarLen <*> getVarLen
    :: Get (ByteString -> Body)
Prr <$> u1 <*> u1 <*> u1 <*> u2 <*> u2 <*> u2 <*> u2 <*> u2 <*> u2 <*> getVarLen <*> getVarLen <*> getVarLen
    :: Get Body
```

It's worth noting that all `Monad`s can be `Applicative`s (and in future versions of GHC, will be required to be).

If `Get` didn't have an `Applicative` instance ([which it does](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.7.0.1/docs/Data-Binary-Get-Internal.html#t:Get)) we could
easily make one from the `Monad` instance:

```
instance Applicative Get where
  pure = return
  mf <*> ma = do
    f <- mf
    a <- ma
    return $ f a
```

Comment: Thanks @rampion. Did you type all that in? I figure you must have some scripts for demonstrating derivations.

Comment: Nah, just vim. `2yyjp` to copy/paste, `A <*> u1<Esc>` to add the next term, `jT(dW` to delete the first function argument.

Comment: Though I suppose I could have done `:normal 2yyjpA <*> ^R=Prompt("term? ")^M^[jT(d2f k` where `Prompt` is a function containing `call inputsave() | let l:result=input(a:prompt) | call inputrestore() | return l:result`, then done `10@:` to produce the rest. Which is sort of scripting.